# Not getting socket response

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I created a file in the root folder, server.js

```js
var socket  = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = require('http').createServer(app);
var io      = socket.listen( server );
var port    = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
        io.sockets.emit( 'new_message', {           
            id: data.id,
            titulo: data.titulo,
            mensagem: data.mensagem,
            created_at: data.created_at
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

Now in an AJAX request, I add the data in the database and return it in JSON.
My return in AJAX, has the following code

```js
if(data.success == true) {
    let socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );
    socket.emit('new_message', {
        id: data.id,
        titulo: data.titulo,
        mensagem: data.mensagem,
        created_at: data.created_at
    });
}
```

And I'm trying to get the socket response as below, but I'm not having success.

```js
let socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );
socket.on( 'new_message', function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: is not socket protocol ws e.g `let socket = io.connect( 'ws://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );`

Comment: on the console, I see the socket working

Comment: I have resolved the problem.

I had to add `header ('Content-Type: application / json');` return Json, it was coming as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. I had to add `header('Content-Type: application / json');` return Json, it was coming as string